# jQuery UI Sortable. Stop one specific item from being dropped into another specific item?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a menu that looks a bit like this.

```
<ul class="sortable">
  <li id="item1">
    <span class="grab"></span>
    <!-- More stuff -->
  </li>
  <li id="item2">
    <span class="grab"></span>
    <!-- More stuff -->
    <ul>
       <!-- Submenu Links -->
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li id="item3">
    <span class="grab"></span>
    <!-- More stuff -->
    <ul>
       <!-- Submenu Links -->
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I have made this sortable. There are multiple menu's. Everything works, it sorts, there are ajax events to save. Its all lovely.

`.item2` and `.item3` are submenus. The only difference between a submenu and link is the presence of the ul.

The problem I have though is that I do not want submenu's to be able to be dropped into other submenu's. They can be moved above or below any links / submenus. They can be moved into any menu. They just cannot be dropped into another submenu.

```
$('.sortable').sortable({
    handle : '.grab', 
    items: "li:not(.no-sort)",
    connectWith: '.sortable',
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        if ( ! $('.prompt.saveOrder').length) {
            $('.prompt').remove();
            $('.content').prepend('<p class="prompt"><a href="'+window.location.pathname+'" class="saveOrder">Click here to save the order of your items</a></p>');
        }
    },
    beforeStop: function(event, ui) {
    }
});
```

I am fairly sure beforeStop is the correct function. Does anyone know how I can achieve this? I don't mind adding a little extra html to make it happen.

Any help / advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: try to change `items: "li:not(.no-sort)",` to `items: "li:not('.no-sort')",` it might work

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('.sortable').sortable({
        handle: '.grab',
        items: ".link",
        connectWith: '.sortable',
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            if (!$('.prompt.saveOrder').length) {
                $('.prompt').remove();
                $('.content').prepend('<p class="prompt"><a href="' + window.location.pathname + '" class="saveOrder">Click here to save the order of your items</a></p>');
            }
        },
        beforeStop: function(event, ui) {}
    });
```

[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/mpwye/3/)

Comment: An exmplanation would be fine :)